# JScrollPane cannot detect text in need of scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

This is a simplified version of my code, if this is not enough to diagnose the problem, comment and I'll post more code:

```
//All Necessary Imports

JFrame window;
Container container;
JPanel mainTextPanel;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
JTextArea mainText;
Font normalFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN,30);

ChoiceHandler choiceHandler = new ChoiceHandler();

//Unrelated Variables

public class setUp()
{
    public setUp()
    {
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(825,600);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        window.setLayout(null);

        container = window.getContentPane();

        mainTextPanel = new JPanel();
        mainTextPanel.setBounds(100,100,600,250);
        mainTextPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        container.add(mainTextPanel);

        //more code goes here
    }
}

public class mainText extends setUp
{
    public mainText()
    {
        mainText = new JTextArea("Tons of text here");
        mainText.setBounds(100,100,600,250);
        mainText.setBackground(Color.white);
        mainText.setForeground(Color.black);
        mainText.setFont(normalFont);
        mainText.setLineWrap(true);
        scrollPane = new 
        JScrollPane(mainText,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        mainTextPanel.add(scrollPane);
        mainTextPanel.revalidate();
        mainTextPanel.repaint();
        mainTextPanel.setVisible(true);

        //more code goes here
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run the code, everything works except that the ScrollPane apparently cannot detect the fact that the text is out of bounds. The scrollbar is there, the only problem is that you cannot scroll with it, it looks like a scroll bar from when the text does not exceed the limit.

When I removed the ALWAYS modifier in creating the scrollbar, the scrollbar disappears, again demonstrating that the scrollbar simply does not detect the out-of-bounds text.

Comment: `window.setLayout(null);` would be my main point of concern

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to point out to you why `null` layouts suck ... code

[image: Why Null layouts suck]

This is how your code appears on my system.  To be honest, there is scroll bar there, but your attempt to do away with the layout management API has caused the `JScrollPane` to exceed the physical bounds of the parent container.

You also don't seem to understand how the coordinate system works in Swing, in relationship to the parent component's context, but if you work with a layout manager instead, you wouldn't need to.

So, after updating your code a bit to use a layout managers

[image: Scrollable]

You know have a solution which can be scrolled...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                mainText mt = new mainText();
                mt.window.pack();
                mt.window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                mt.window.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public class setUp {

        JFrame window;
        Container container;
        JPanel mainTextPanel;
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        JTextArea mainText;
        Font normalFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 30);

        public setUp() {
            window = new JFrame();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);

            container = window.getContentPane();

            mainTextPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            mainTextPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            container.add(mainTextPanel);

            //more code goes here
        }
    }

    public class mainText extends setUp {

        public mainText() {
            mainText = new JTextArea("Tons of text here");
            mainText.setBackground(Color.white);
            mainText.setForeground(Color.black);
            mainText.setFont(normalFont);
            mainText.setLineWrap(true);
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainText, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

            mainTextPanel.add(scrollPane);
            mainTextPanel.revalidate();
            mainTextPanel.repaint();

            //more code goes here
        }
    }

}
```

> But where is the horizontal scroll bar?

`mainText.setLineWrap(true);` would have removed the need for it

> But the `JTextArea` is to small!

So?  Supply some appropriate sizing hints which the component can use to make better determinations about how large it might like to be.

Something like `mainText = new JTextArea("Tons of text here", 1, 10);` produces

[image: Long text]

So, the long and short answer is, use the layout management API, Swing has been designed around it's use and it will save you a lot of head scratching and stupid edge cases

> But on my system the scroll bars don't appear!?

Go back to the start, do not collect $200 and read it again. The reason why it would appear differently is because of the lack of layout support

> But I don't want to use/understand layout managers!

Tough.  If you want to avoid these kind of "weird" issues, then the layout management API is the right direction to head in.  Take the time to experiment with the different layout managers and try different combinations, you're not stuck to using just one, almost all complex UIs will make use a at least two if not more layout managers in a single compound UI

Comment: I'll start experimenting with layouts immediately. Thanks for all the time you spent creating this!